# Labeling the (p,q,r)-pretzel knot with transpositions from S4

Tags: geometric-topology, knot-theory

For what values of p,q, and r, can the (p,q,r)-pretzel knot be labeled with transpositions from $S_4$?  I'm kind of stuck on how to approach this one.  All I've got so far is that there are six transpositions in $S_4$ so I'm assuming there have to be at least six strands.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am a little confused as to what you are trying to do here.  Can you elaborate on how you want to label the pretzel knot?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out for what values of p,q, and r I can label a (p,q,r) pretzel knot with the transposition elements from the symmetry group $S_4$.